# Symfony Validator: validate entity is unique and return the duplicate entity if it isn't?

Tags: php, symfony, validation

In my Symfony application, when creating or updating a certain entity, I would like to check whether a duplicate entity already exists, and if it does, display an URL to the existing entity's page together with the error message.

I use Symfony's Validator component with custom constraint classes for my validation, to have reusable validators in different parts of the application - the web controller, console commands, batch processing scripts, etc. I would like `$validator->validate($entity)` to validate entity uniqueness as well, using a custom `UniqueEntityConstraint`

However, I cannot find a way to do this - there doesn't appear to be any way to pass an object from a `Constraint Validator` back to the controller.

Is there a way to do what I need using the `Validator` component, or am I at a dead end?

Solutions I've explored so far:

1. `DoctrineBridgeBundle`'s `UniqueEntity` constraint.

Doesn't return the existing entity or even its ID, just a message that it exists.

2. Extend `ConstraintViolation` with a getDuplicateEntity() method.

This would be the optimal solution, but it doesn't work - there appears to be no way to use a custom class without overriding core Symfony code.

3. Store the duplicate entity on the Constraint itself and retrieve it using `$violation->getConstraint()->getDuplicateEntity()`.

It would be a dirty hack even if it worked, but it doesn't - `ConstraintValidators` reuse the same Constraint instance, so if you were validating multiple entities in a row, `getDuplicateEntity()` would only get you the last duplicate from the batch.

Comment: Why do you want to redefine a custom UniqueEntityConstraint ?

Comment: Your best bet would be to simply query the duplicate entity from your controller.  Trying to add return values to validators would be challenging. 
 However, for option 3, use an array and Constraint::getDuplicateEntries().  Might also consider injecting the event manager into your custom constraint and then sending an event whenever a dup was found.  A listener (which could be your controller) would pick it up.  Possibly the least hackish approach.

Comment: As you know which field is causing the validation error, try/catch around the persist and query the existing entity by the unique field with the given value, like @Cerad suggested.

Comment: If your entity uniqueness condition is more complex than a UNIQUE index (for example, you must ensure only one event of a type is scheduled during a given time frame), then you cannot enforce it with a try/catch around the persist. 

Catching the validation error and then re-querying the existing entity can end in awkward race condition (there was a duplicate when the user clicked "Submit" and triggered the ValidatorConstraint error, but it's gone by the time the controller queries the duplicate entity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, this is not possible to do with the Validator component. If you want your validation checks to return more than string error messages, you should write a custom service.

I've submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23965) to potentially make this possible in the future.